# Can't insert into linked MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I want to insert a new rows into database in MySQL server from SQL Server Management Studio. To make it possible I've created a linked server in SMSS with this guide: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-to-connect-to-mysql-in-sql-server-management-studio/ .
I'm using next:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2022,
- MySQL Server 5.8,
- SQL Server Management Studio 2019,
- MySQL Server Workbench 8.0.

I was trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO [MYSQL]...[cclog_db].[companies] (id, company_code, name)
VALUES (5, 5 , 'Random Company');
```

Where "MYSQL" is a name of a linked server, "testdb" is a name of DB in MySQL Server, "companies" is a name of a table.
As a result I got next:

> Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> The name 'MYSQL...cclog_db.companies' exceeds the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum number is 3.。

> Completion time: 2023-07-12T09:29:59.3909575+09:00

Is there is a way to insert new rows to MySQl server from SQL Server? Also is there is a way to copy data from the same table in SQL Server to MySql server?

Comment: There is no version 5.8 of MySQL. It's either version 5.7 or v8.0.x

Comment: Too many dots `[MYSQL]...[cclog_db].[companies]` should be `[MYSQL]..[cclog_db].[companies]` or `[MYSQL].[cclog_db]..[companies]`

Answer (score -2):

This error means that mysql columns can't store so many characters. varchar is recommended. You can turn it up, for example, from varchar (50) to Varchar (200).